# SQL Server Top Run ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a bunch of risk numbers that get processed each time the numbers are calculated, so on each day there are maybe 2 or more risk numbers. Each time they are calculated, a run id is stored.

How can I obtain for the month of November, the risk number for the top run id?

I tried this query:

```
select a.ptf_id,a.analysis_date, a.report_run_id, a.bps
from rpt.rm_Report_History a
where a.ptf_id=336
and a.criteria_Set = 'Daily'
and a.report_section_group = 'Key_Risk_Figures'
and a.rm_rcp_param_name = 'Fund'
and a.stat_class = 'standaloneVaR'
and a.analysis_date>'2016-10-28'
```

which gives the following output:

[image]

Comment: what is *risk number*? What determines *top*?

Comment: The top run id is the latest risk number available for a given portfolio, in this case portfolio 336

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the value for each date, then `row_number()` comes to mind:

```
select a.*
from (select a.ptf_id, a.analysis_date, a.report_run_id, a.bps,
             row_number() over (partition by a.analysis_date order by a.report_run_id desc) as seqnum
      from rpt.rm_Report_History a
      where a.ptf_id = 336 and
            a.criteria_Set = 'Daily' and
            a.report_section_group = 'Key_Risk_Figures' and
            a.rm_rcp_param_name = 'Fund' and
            a.stat_class = 'standaloneVaR' and
            a.analysis_date >= '2016-11-01' and
            a.analysis_date < '2016-12-01' 
     ) a
where seqnum = 1;
```

I'm not sure how you define the month of "November".  The above uses the calendar month.

Comment: This returns 1 row, for the 29th November

Comment: Is that not what you want?  The top answer to [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) contains some great tips for posting SQL questions.

Comment: For EACH date i need the risk number that corresponds to the top run id

Comment: @Patrick . . . I changed the answer based on your comment.  However, your question is "How can I obtain for the month of November, the risk number for the top run id?".  That says nothing about the top per day.

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**, I am also not pretty much sure about your requirement but if you want the records from the `TOP 1` `run_id` from the given criteria

```
select a.ptf_id,a.analysis_date, a.report_run_id, a.bps
from rpt.rm_Report_History a
inner join (select max(run_id) as run_id
        from rpt.rm_Report_History a
        where a.ptf_id=336
        and a.criteria_Set = 'Daily'
        and a.report_section_group = 'Key_Risk_Figures'
        and a.rm_rcp_param_name = 'Fund'
        and a.stat_class = 'standaloneVaR'
        and a.analysis_date>'2016-10-28') b on b.run_id = a.run_id
```

if you want to retrieve november data only then use `between`, `> AND <` as below otherwise it will return add data where analysis date is greater than the defined date

```
and a.analysis_date between '2016-09-01' AND '2016-09-30'
OR
and a.analysis_date >= '2016-09-01' AND a.analysis_date <= '2016-09-30'
```